# $C^1$ functions and proving that $f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)(f'(a) + h(x))$ where $h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm reading Howie, Complex Analysis, and in section $1.5$, which is a brief review of real analysis, he writes if $f'$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$ then
$$
f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)( f'(a) + h(x))
$$
where $h(x) \to 0$ as $x\to a$.

I really don't see what the continuity of $f'$ has to do with this since I could write
$$
h(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} - f'(a)
$$
and by differentiability of $f$ I obtain $h(x) \to 0$ as $x\to a$ as required.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don’t think you are missing anything

Comment: It is over-condition as you pointed out. Maybe the author thought of writing $h(x) = f'(c)-f'(a)$ by mean value theorem, where $c$ is near $a$, and concluding by continuity of $f'$.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.